# How do I print a decrementing pattern of asterisks where the asterisks are replaced with spaces in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to print this pattern with a C program, where it starts with 10 asterisks, and decrements by one each time it prints, replacing the asterisk with a space instead. I am very new to C programming and have no idea what I'm doing, so the most I've been able to do is get the asterisks to print and decrement by one, but without the spaces.

This is the pattern I am trying to get.   I had to represent the asterisks with A and spaces with S to get it to print properly on stackoverflow.  I had to re-ask my question because it didn't format properly the first time.

```
AAAAAAAAAA↵
SAAAAAAAAA↵
SSAAAAAAAA↵
SSSAAAAAAA↵
SSSSAAAAAA↵
SSSSSAAAAA↵
SSSSSSAAAA↵
SSSSSSSAAA↵
SSSSSSSSAA↵
SSSSSSSSSA↵
```

This is the pattern I currently get.

```
A↵
SA↵
SSA↵
SSSA↵
SSSSA↵
SSSSSA↵
SSSSSSA↵
SSSSSSSA↵
SSSSSSSSA↵
SSSSSSSSSA↵
```

My code looks like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
for(int x=1; x<=i; x++){
    printf(x<i ? " " : "*");
}
printf("\n");
}
```

As you can see, I can increment the spaces no problem, but I am not starting out with the appropriate number of asterisks.

Comment: Thank you ggorlen for the formatting assistance.

Comment: No problem and welcome to SO! Try running your inner loop to 10 to fill the line.

Comment: Do you mean writing `printf(x<10 ? " " : "*"); instead of x<i?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb, I did what you said and had the inner for loop do x<=10, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
for( int n = 1; n <= 10; ++n){
    for( int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        printf(" ");
    for( int j = 10; j >= n; --j)
        printf("*");
    printf("\n");
}
```

This code worked for me as the solution to what the original asker wanted to do. I used two inner for-loops to print the space and asterisk in the increment and decrement manner respectively. I used an exclusive "less than" condition on the outer so the first row printed from the beginning.